# Partitions name on startup boot selection are listed with the wrong name

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, startup

I partitioned a USB hard drive as above

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS 10_13_6 macOS High S... 31.7 GB    disk4s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS 10_14 macOs Mojave      32.7 GB    disk4s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Stuff                   869.4 GB   disk4s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS 10_11 OS X El Capitan   32.0 GB    disk4s5
   6:                  Apple_HFS 10_12 macOs Sierra      33.5 GB    disk4s6
```

4 partitions can boot the installation of a specific OSX/macOs. The problem is that at the boot I don't see the partition name for all the partition installed with [macOs patcher](http://www.dosdude1.com/software.html) but I see a generic `OS X Base System`. The only partition with the correct name is the one I created without the `macOs patcher`.

[image: mac boot options]

I tried to change the name of a partition, but all is fine on the desktop. Here the info from `diskutil` of one of those partitions.

```
$ diskutil info /dev/disk4s2
   Device Identifier:        disk4s2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk4s2
   Whole:                    No
   Part of Whole:            disk4

   Volume Name:              10_13_6 macOS High Sierra
   Mounted:                  No

   Partition Type:           Apple_HFS
   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Journal:                  Unknown (not mounted)
   Owners:                   Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              8B95E95F-3474-35EC-9AE2-9ADF9DCB9D9B
   Disk / Partition UUID:    E48E93FD-D30E-4565-A22E-C5F18B295AD4
   Partition Offset:         209735680 Bytes (409640 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                31.7 GB (31723995136 Bytes) (exactly 61960928 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:       0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:          External
   Removable Media:          Fixed
```

I don't understand where the boot option gets the label of the partition and how to change it! Any idea?